# Why does the Dirac delta function satisfy $f(x)\delta(x-a) = f(a)\delta(x-a)$?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Why does the Dirac delta function have the property that 
$$ f(x)\delta(x-a)= f(a)\delta(x-a) , $$
where $\delta(x-a)$ is the Dirac delta function? Won't the Dirac delta function just stay the same even after being multiplied?

Comment: $ \delta(x)$ is a distribution (not a function) with the property that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \delta(x) h(x) dx = h(0)$ for any continuous function $h$, thus if $f$ is continuous then for every continuous function $h$ : $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \delta(x-a) f(x) h(x) dx = h(a)f(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \delta(x-a) f(a) h(x) dx$ and $ \delta(x-a) f(x) =  \delta(x-a) f(a)$ as distributions

Comment: Because $\delta(x)=0$ for $x\ne 0$. The same equation for example holds for the function that is $1$ for $x=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @celtschk no. At first distirbutions act on $C^\infty$ functions with compact support , and you can extend distributions of order $k$ to act on $C^k$ functions, but not on something as $h(x)  = 0$ for $x\ne 0$, $h(0)  = 1$ (well in fact you can but then $h \equiv 0$ the function zero-everywhere )

Comment: "Won't the Diract delta function just stay the same even after being multiplied?"  I think that for intuition it's useful to think of $\delta$ as being an extremely narrow (but smooth) spike, centered at the origin, with area under the curve equal to $1$.

Comment: @littleO I think for the intuition we need to think to it as what it is : a limit, for example $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) h(x)dx= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{|x| < \epsilon}h(x)dx$

Comment: $\delta(\tau)=0$ *by definition* when $\tau\neq0$. $\tau=x-a=0$ will give you $x=a$.

Answer (score 5):

The definition of the dirac delta is an object $\delta$ such that, for any (suitably well behaved) function $f$, $$\int_{a}^{b}\delta(x)f(x)dx $$
takes the value $f(0)$ if $a<0<b$, and $0$ otherwise. This isn't really a function, as there is provably no function $\delta: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with this property. If it's not a function, then what the hell is it? Well, as the other answers point out, $\delta$ is formally defined as something called a *distribution*. However, it turns out you can manipulate $\delta$ as though it were a function, and in surprisingly many cases the sky does not fall on your head.

Fixing an $a \in \mathbb{R}$, it is then immediate from the definition that
$$\int_{c}^{d}\delta(x-a)f(x)dx=\int_{c}^{d}f(a)\delta(x-a)dx$$
for any choice of $c$ and $d$, because both sides are equal to $f(a)$ when $a \in [c,d]$, and $0$ otherwise.
It seems that what the question setter has done is then equate the integrands, and say that the objects $$f(x)\delta(x-a)=f(a)\delta(x-a)$$
are the same. In my opinion this is a strange thing to say, because it suggests that you are treating $\delta$ as though it were a real function, which it is not.

Comment: So, in your initial definition of $f$, could we interpret the value $f(0)$ arising from $\int \delta (x-0)f(x) dx$?

Comment: If you wanted to, sure.

Answer (score 2):

The only correct way to see it is from the distributional theory of the Delta function. Indeed, for a test function $\phi$, we have:

$$\langle \delta(x-a), \phi(x)\rangle = \langle \theta'(x-a), \phi(x)\rangle = - \langle \theta(x-a), \phi'(x)\rangle  = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi'(x)\theta(x-a)\ \text{d}x$$

Now since we have a $\theta$, we know that that $\theta(x-a) = 1$ for $x-a\geq0$ and $0$ otherwise. Hence the integral becomes

$$-\int_{a}^{+\infty}\phi'(x)\theta(x-a)\ \text{d}x = -\phi(x)\bigg|_{a}^{+\infty}$$

The test function $\phi$ goes to zero for $x\to \infty$ hence you remain with

$$\phi(a)$$

This shows you that the action of the $\delta(x-a)$ on a function $f(x)$ gives you

$$f(a)$$

Now the reason why the Dirac Delta remains, it's because the expression $f(x)\delta(x-a)$ makes sense only in the support of the Delta which is $x = a$, otherwise it's zero. To remark this, you write $f(x)\delta(x-a)$ because every other value for $x$ is meaningless.

Comment: for differentiating $\delta(x)$ you need some sort of distribution theory, but you can define $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)h(x)dx$ as $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|x|<\epsilon}}{2\epsilon} h(x)dx$ whenever it converges, in particular when $h$ is continuous at $x=0$

Comment: @user1952009 Indeed I used the theory of distributions, so I'm safe and sound.

Comment: the problem is that you have to learn $\delta(x)$ for the Fourier transform, before learning the distributions. And $\delta(x),\delta$ appears naturally in the dual of $C_0,C^1$ or $L^p,W^{1,p}$ spaces

Comment: @user1952009 Nope. Fourier transform comes AFTER. First of all you need the theory of distributions. You cannot run FT without knowing already distributions.

Comment: Well nobody learn distributions before the Fourier transform, and the Fourier transform at first is defined for $L^1,L^2$ and the Schwartz space, but then $\delta(x)$ naturally appears

Comment: @user1952009 Also, what I did here has nothing to do with FT. It's just the distributional derivative!

Comment: Other and last argument : $\delta(x)$ (the periodic one) naturally appears as the limit of the Dirichlet kernel in the Fourier series, 2 or 3 years before you learn the distributions

Comment: Our professor, who was PERFECT, taught us distributions BEFORE, which makes sense. I don't know where you learnt this stuff but I always feel astonished more and more by the other countries poor way of teaching those topics.

Comment: @user1952009 2 or 3 years?? OH MY GOD where did you study?? We solved the heat equation with FT during the very first year of university! We learnt all that stuff during the FIRST YEAR, not after 3 years! : O

Comment: You are funny. Say Fourier series = 1st and 2nd undergraduate year, Fourier transform and basic functional analysis 2nd and 3rd yr, distributions and operator theory 3rd yr and graduate

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not funny. I'm just sorry and sad, because every day I'm just seeing a poor teaching everywhere. Now I get why the most of countries are not brilliant in maths and physics. lol. 3 years to learn distributions and Delta... Ridiculous.

Comment: Obviously you don't know how maths are teached, look at any programs

Answer (score 2):

Remember that 
the $\delta$ ''function'' is not really a function (proper or “improper”) but a different mathematical object ( a [**distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29)) that live always in the shade of an integral sign.

So, when we write an ''identity'' as:
$$ f(x)\delta(x-a)= f(a)\delta(x-a) , $$
The meaning of this equations is that:

> its two sides give equivalent results when used as factors in an integrand.

And this is easy verified using the definition 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0)$$
for $x-a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The delta distribution is defined as

$\delta: C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\,\phi \mapsto \phi(0)$

i.e. a (continuous, whatever this means) functional on the smooth functions of compact support.
Now translating a delta distribution amounts to translating its argument into the opposite direction:

$\tau_{a}\delta(\phi) := \delta(\tau_{-a}\phi) = \phi(a)$
where $(\tau_{b}\phi)(x) := \phi(x-b)$.

If we now define the product of the delta distribution $\delta$ with a smooth funtion $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ as merely evaluating a test function $\phi$ via the product $f\phi$, you get

$(f\cdot\delta)(\phi) := \delta(f\phi) = f(0)\phi(0)  = \delta(f(0)\phi) = (f(0)\cdot\delta)(\phi)$

and in this sense you have $f\cdot\delta = f(0)\cdot\delta$. Together with the above, the full claim follows.

Comment: I think this is the best answer here. I am not sure about the "merely evaluating' though. Is there something not clearly defined in the expression below? I would write $\langle f(x)\delta_a,\phi(x)\rangle=\langle \delta_a,f(x)\phi(x)\rangle=f(a)\phi(a)=f(a)\langle \delta_a,\phi(x)\rangle=\langle f(a)\delta_a,\phi(x)\rangle$ hence $f(x)\delta_a=f(a)\delta_a$

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that cancelling the Dirac "function" on both sides is not allowed.

Why?

Because the function equals zero for $x$ not equal to $a$. And if $x=a$, the value becomes infinity. The rules of maths don't allow for direct cancellation of zeroes or infinities on both the sides.

Answer (score 0):

"Physicists rush in where mathematicians fear to tread". Let's dance.

There are a few definitions of $\delta(x)$ that give intuition.

If we start with the propertyt hat $\int_a^b\delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$ when $a<x<b$, then we can get a definition:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)e^{-ikx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. The Fourier Transform of the dirac delta function is a constant, so the inverse Fourier Transform is that original function:

$\delta(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}dk$

In many cases, a suitable curve with finite area will do.

$\delta(x)=\lim _{\alpha\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}} e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$. This holds for arbitrary positive values of $\alpha$. As alpha increases, the height increases, but the width shrinks, maintaining unit area. We essentially have an infinitely high, infinitely narrow curve and this is one characterization of the dirac-delta function.

Given one of these definitions, we can plug it into the integral as we would the diract delta function directly:

$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int_a^b \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}}e^{-\alpha(x-c)^2}f(x)dx$

Then with $u$ substitution $u=x-c, du=dx$:

$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int_{a-c}^{b-c}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}}e^{-\alpha u^2}f(u+c)du=f(c)$ for suitable $f$ and associated interval.