# Derivative of Dirac $\delta$ times a smooth function

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory

Suppose we have a test function $\phi$ and the expression:
$$\int_\mathbb{R}\phi(x)\delta(x-a)dx $$

next, we would like to multiply by a $h(x)\in C^\infty$ function and then take the derivative of the combined expression. which of the following is correct (or are they equivalent)?

(1)
$$\int\phi(x)h(x)\delta(x)dx= \int\phi(x)h(a)\delta(x)dx$$
then differentiating (treating $h(a)$ as constant):
as per the first comment in [Why does the Dirac delta function satisfy $f(x)\delta(x-a) = f(a)\delta(x-a)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947782/why-does-the-dirac-delta-function-satisfy-fx-deltax-a-fa-deltax-a)

(2) or using the product rule:
$$\int\phi(x)h(a)\delta'(x)dx+\int\phi(a)h(x)\delta'(x)dx $$

Comment: [ith order derivative of dirac delta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyvdO.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Since $\phi\in C_C^\infty$ and $h\in C^\infty$, then $\phi h\in C_C^\infty$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \delta_a', \phi h\rangle&=-\langle \delta_a, (\phi h)'\rangle\\\\
&=-\langle \delta_a, \phi'h+\phi h'\rangle\\\\
&=-\phi'(a)h(a)-\phi(a)h'(a)\\\\
&=\langle \delta_a',h(a)\phi+\phi(a)h\rangle \\\\
&=\langle \delta_a',h(a)\phi\rangle +\langle \delta_a',\phi(a)h\rangle 
\end{align}$$